# Pushing to Power BI REST API without user intervention

Tags: powerbi

My goal is to periodically push data to a Power BI dataset using their REST API without user intervention.

It seems like the only way that's currently possible is to configure user credentials into the application and authenticate that way. All examples of the 'App Owns Data' strategy require some sort of user/password credentials.

I wrote an Azure WebJob that uses the credentials of a service account we created to authenticate with Azure AD and it's successfully pushing data to Power BI, but I'd like to do avoid having a service account just for this as it has cost and security implications.

Is there a way to use the Power BI REST API without user intervention and without logging in using Azure AD credentials?

Comment: The App-Owns-Data paradigm is business speak for Use-Service-Account. It might be possible to generate a token from an existing non-service account and then embed that token in your deployment code (rather than the username password). However I suspect the security model that Microsoft uses is more robust, and the tokens will be session-based. Some APIs allow users to generate an Authentication token (long-term access) and then use a handshake to provide an Authorization token. Right now, I don't think MS PBI API allows for both tokens to achieve what you're describing.